# How can I update a map using the `update` function?

Tags: clojure

```
   (def p {:name "James" :age 26})
```

I'm trying update method, like

```
(update p :name "David")
```

which does not work since the second argument has to be a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(assoc p :name "David")
```

Please see this [list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), especially the [Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)!  See also `assoc-in` and `update-in` as described under

```
Collections -> Maps
```

---

**P.S.** What you have there is a Clojure map value, which is different than an object in JavaScript or a JSON string.